# Server 2008 will not boot after mobo swap

Tags: boot, motherboard, uefi, windows-server-2008-r2, raid-1

Current Spec: 
Intel i3-3220
GA-H77-DS3H (New)
1x8gb ddr3 1600
2x500 gb WDC wd5003abyx drives; raid1 
windows server 2008 R2 foundation

The system was working fine utilizing the gigabyte GA-h77m-d3h and hung during a shutdown. The system was force powered off, and upon restart was indicating a memory error. (3 short beeps small pause, 3 more short beeps) Once I was sure the memory was fine (tested known good sticks, and original stick on different mobo) I found the closest motherboard I could to the original.

Upon installation the computer posted fine but I was greeted with "your computer did not shutdown properly, option to repair or boot normal. Tried booting normal and received *Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause* error code 0x000000e

When booting from installation media, when I attempt to repair I am greeted with "this version of system recovery options is not compatible with the version of windows you are trying to repair. I believe that is do to the disk being raid1. -- I am able to disconnect one of the drives to receive some options of getting into the command prompt etc.

Boot Option1: Intel Raid
Boot Option2: UEFI DVDRam
Sata Controllers: Enabled 
Sata Mode Selection: Raid

Any advise where to go from here? Can I break the raid1 and not have any data loss?

Note* I know you should reinstall for a mobo or major hardware swap but I did not have that option unfortunately, and was hoping with a similar enough chipset everything could work out.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the RAID controller indicate a healthy RAID 1 array? You should see the status during POST.

Comment: Not what you want to hear, but if you had memory issues, you probably have data corruption anyway.  I wouldn't try to rescue that Windows installation.

Comment: @Appleddity 

Status of the Raid 1 is Rebuild, and indicates it is bootable disk. 

This seems to be the first issue with the memory. Had worked well for 3 years, and this boot it indicated bad ram and wouldn't post. You think that would have corrupted the windows install?